# monaco-editor: what do I need to get access to the typescript worker?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

In my application, I am using the monaco-editor as a playground-environment where users can edit and run typescript code.

This used to work in monaco-editor up to v0.40.0, but since upgrading to v0.41.0 I just get an error-message "TypeScript not registered!". What do I need to do to 'register' TypeScript?

To run the code, I use an editor-action like this:

```
editorInstance.addAction({
    id: 'compile-and-run',
    label: 'Compile and run',
    keybindings: [KeyMod.CtrlCmd | KeyCode.Enter],
    async run() {
      const model = editorInstance.getModel();

      if (!model) {
        console.error('compile-and-run: no editor-model found.');
        return;
      }
      
      const worker = await languages.typescript.getTypeScriptWorker();
      const proxy = await worker(model.uri);

      const {outputFiles} = await proxy.getEmitOutput(model.uri.toString());
      const jsCode = outputFiles[0].text;

      await runJsCode(jsCode);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the typescript worker to compile your code. I even do this without the editor. To fix the registration you need the following code.

```
  private initDone = false;
  private ensureTypeScriptRegistration() {
    if (!this.initDone) {
      // fix "TypeScript not registered!" when skipping the creation of the editor
      const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.createElement('div'));
      editor.dispose();
      this.initDone = true;
    }
  }
```